# Don't understand this dictionary changed size during iteration error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to execute below code but it gives me `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` even though I'm not deleting the key.

Can somebody help me to understand where am I doing wrong?

This is for Python 3.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
class Solution(object):
    def findOrder(self, numCourses, prerequisites):
        """
        :type numCourses: int
        :type prerequisites: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        def create_graph():
            for course in prerequisites:
                child, pare = course[0], course[1]
                graph[child].append(pare)

        graph = defaultdict(list)
        create_graph()

        def topological_order(node):

            visited.add(node)
            visiting.add(node)

            for nei in graph[node]:
                if nei in visiting:
                    return False
                if nei not in visited:
                    rs = topological_order(nei)
                    if not rs:
                        return False

            visiting.remove(node)
            result.append(node)
            return True


        result = []
        visited = set()
        visiting = set()

        for nd in graph.keys():
            if nd not in visited:
                rs = topological_order(nd)
                if not rs:
                    return []

        return result

obj = Solution()
print( obj.findOrder(4, [[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]]) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a defaultdict.

If you access it with a not yet present key, it will create this key and add the `[]` as default value.

When debugging your code, this happens with the value of key `1` when recursing with its 0-value into `rs = topological_order(0)` and then iterating it as key in `for nei in graph[0]:` which creates `{0:[]}`.

> ```
>     def topological_order(node):
>
>         visited.add(node)
>         visiting.add(node)
>
>         for nei in graph[node]:      # this line adds unknown keys with default value []
>             if nei not in visited:
>                 rs = topological_order(nei)
>                 if not rs:
>                     return False
> ```

This happens on iterating

```
for nd in graph.keys(): # first key is 1
    if nd not in visited:
        rs = topological_order(nd) # calls it with 1 then inside recurses on 0 which 
                                   # modifies the dictionary.
        if not rs:
            return []

return result
```

You can guard against it, by not accessing the key if not present in by checking with if first. Not sure if that makes sense for what you try to do.

You could operate on a copy of the dictionary keys:

```
    for nd in list(graph.keys()):
        if nd not in visited:
            rs = topological_order(nd)
            if not rs:
                return []

    return result
```

which will ignore added keys - not sure if that helps either.